# How do I reduce the space between title and chart of a High Chart?

Tags: highcharts

I try to hide the title in this way:

```
title: {
    text: '',
    style: {
        display: 'none'
    }
},
```

But even the title is gone, there are still plenty of unwanted room above my chart. Which would be very precious on mobile screens.

Is there any way to reduce them?

Comment: You tried setting `margin:0` or even negative margin ? `title: {   margin: 0  }`

Comment: Tried but not working :(

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Can you make a JSFiddle for it? What I just tried seemed fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vR9nB/

Comment: Also you can disable margin/spacing by parameters: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

Answer (score 3):

Set the title's [margin](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.margin)

```
    title: {
        margin: 0
    },
```

JSFiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/title/margin-50/